# Как найти столбец с определенным значением в dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть датафрейм (привожу фрагмент). Нужно вывести пары столбец+строка для всех имеющихся максимальных значений.

```
                          roadMiles    DeltaT  DeltaTsquared  lnDeltaT  \
year                  -3.225463e-15  0.657572       0.595630  0.663712   
rcp                    1.696726e-18  0.394061       0.396570  0.356670   
slr_scen                        NaN       NaN            NaN       NaN   
damage                 1.523673e-01  0.203318       0.202560  0.187230   
damageScaled          -1.239285e-02  0.005697       0.010683 -0.000287   
lnDamage               1.877514e-01  0.174575       0.162085  0.175694   
lnDamageScaled        -6.387636e-02  0.054137       0.052575  0.048905   
coastalPropertyValues  8.527952e-01  0.019845       0.008842  0.044558   
railMiles              9.824199e-01  0.082111       0.064033  0.110883   
population             7.096372e-01  0.106695       0.077487  0.141066   
aeroPop                3.274044e-01  0.107277       0.081588  0.123625   
ETcity_population      2.442220e-01  0.112426       0.096392  0.128789   
suscBridges            9.573839e-01  0.072022       0.051011  0.104922   
UDcity_landArea_sqmi   6.595350e-01 -0.065551      -0.081078 -0.037903   
roadMiles              0.000000e+00  0.059291       0.040203  0.090714   
DeltaT                 5.929084e-02  0.000000       0.969735  0.950863   
DeltaTsquared          4.020292e-02  0.969735       0.000000  0.854277   
lnDeltaT               9.071426e-02  0.950863       0.854277  0.000000   
RatP                  -7.008078e-02  0.224603       0.227717  0.207068   
slr                             NaN       NaN            NaN       NaN   
slrSquared                      NaN       NaN            NaN       NaN
```

Уже есть столбцы и максимальные значения в каждом из них. Как найти от них строки, как вывести пары столбец+строка?

Например: year_lnDeltaT, rcp_DeltaTsquared

```
year                     0.663712
rcp                      0.396570
slr_scen                 0.585095
damage                   0.516559
damageScaled             0.477802
lnDamage                 0.519589
lnDamageScaled           0.519589
coastalPropertyValues    0.874368
railMiles                0.982420
population               0.999407
aeroPop                  0.999407
ETcity_population        0.775525
suscBridges              0.957384
UDcity_landArea_sqmi     0.796167
roadMiles                0.982420
DeltaT                   0.969735
DeltaTsquared            0.969735
lnDeltaT                 0.950863
RatP                     0.227717
slr                      0.952548
slrSquared               0.952548
```

Answer (score 3):

Воспользуйтесь методом [pandas.DataFrame.idxmax](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.idxmax.html) с указанием оси:

```
res = df.idxmax(axis=1)
```

в вашем случае `res` получится:

```
year                          lnDeltaT
rcp                      DeltaTsquared
slr_scen                           NaN
damage                          DeltaT
damageScaled             DeltaTsquared
lnDamage                     roadMiles
lnDamageScaled                  DeltaT
coastalPropertyValues        roadMiles
railMiles                    roadMiles
population                   roadMiles
aeroPop                      roadMiles
ETcity_population            roadMiles
suscBridges                  roadMiles
UDcity_landArea_sqmi         roadMiles
roadMiles                     lnDeltaT
DeltaT                   DeltaTsquared
DeltaTsquared                   DeltaT
lnDeltaT                        DeltaT
RatP                     DeltaTsquared
slr                                NaN
slrSquared                         NaN
```

Если вам нужно эту серию сложить в строки, то сделать это можно так:

```
lst = ([f"{x[0]}_{x[1]}" for x in zip(res.index, res)])
```

lst:

```
['year_lnDeltaT', 'rcp_DeltaTsquared', 'slr_scen_nan', 'damage_DeltaT', 'damageScaled_DeltaTsquared', 'lnDamage_roadMiles', 'lnDamageScaled_DeltaT', 'coastalPropertyValues_roadMiles', 'railMiles_roadMiles', 'population_roadMiles', 'aeroPop_roadMiles', 'ETcity_population_roadMiles', 'suscBridges_roadMiles', 'UDcity_landArea_sqmi_roadMiles', 'roadMiles_lnDeltaT', 'DeltaT_DeltaTsquared', 'DeltaTsquared_DeltaT', 'lnDeltaT_DeltaT', 'RatP_DeltaTsquared', 'slr_nan', 'slrSquared_nan']
```

Answer (score 0):

список можно получить еще вот так:

```
df.index.str.cat(df.idxmax(axis=1),'_','NaN').tolist()
'''
['year_lnDeltaT',
 'rcp_DeltaTsquared',
 'slr_scen_NaN',
 'damage_DeltaT',
 'damageScaled_DeltaTsquared',
 'lnDamage_roadMiles',
 'lnDamageScaled_DeltaT',
 'coastalPropertyValues_roadMiles',
 'railMiles_roadMiles',
 'population_roadMiles',
 'aeroPop_roadMiles',
 'ETcity_population_roadMiles',
 'suscBridges_roadMiles',
 'UDcity_landArea_sqmi_roadMiles',
 'roadMiles_lnDeltaT',
 'DeltaT_DeltaTsquared',
 'DeltaTsquared_DeltaT',
 'lnDeltaT_DeltaT',
 'RatP_DeltaTsquared',
 'slr_NaN',
 'slrSquared_NaN']
```